# Javascript style closure in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, closures

First off, apologies as this title probably made some of you c++ guys throw up in your mouth a little bit. However, let me explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm passing a lambda (call it funcA) as a parameter to another function (call it funcB). Is there a way for me to declare variables within funcB and access them within the scope of funcA without passing them to funcA as parameters, similar to how javascript closures work?

A simple example (which fails obviously) would be as follows:

```
void funcB(std::function<void()> funcA) {
    int testInt = 44;
    funcA();
}

int main() {
    funcB([&]() {
        std::cout << testInt; // undefined identifier
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In short: Not possible.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid passing arguments?

Comment: Can you show respective JavaScript example? This sounds like you want lambda capture, but example is written a in strange way.

Comment: Btw its either `cout << testInt` or `cin >> testInt`.

Comment: @n314159 `cout` error fixed

Comment: @MarekR I believe you are correct. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I had misunderstood exactly what was going on within javascript that was allowing this behavior to occur. After digging in deeper I see now that the only time variables are available within closures are when the variable definition is within the parent scope of the closure definition as such:

```
var funcB = function(funcA){
    funcA();
};

(function(){

  var firstVar = 1;
  var secondVar = 2;

  funcB(function(){
    alert(firstVar + secondVar);
  });

})();
```

This same behavior could be achieved using [lambda capture](https://thispointer.com/c11-lambda-how-to-capture-local-variables-inside-lambda/) (as suggested by user @Marek R in question comments) in C++ as follows:

```
void funcB(std::function<void()> funcA) {
    funcA();
}

int main() {

    int firstVar = 1;
    int secondVar = 2;

    funcB([&]() {

        std::cout << firstVar + secondVar;

    });

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Therefore my original question stemmed from not knowing what I didn't know. To achieve what I am actually after, I will have to pass parameters to my lambda or implement a different design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this particular example the idiomatic way would be to use the return value:

```
void funcB(std::function<int()> funcA) {
    int testInt = funcA();
}

int main() {
    funcB([&]() {
        int testInt = 44;
        std::cout >> testInt;
        return testInt;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Output parameter can be used but less usual:

```
void funcB(std::function<void(int&)> funcA) {
    int testInt = 44;
    funcA(testInt);
}

int main() {
    funcB([&](int& testInt) {
        std::cout >> testInt;
    });

    return 0;
}
```